# How to switch NVM environments within perl

Tags: perl, nvm

I am writing a perl script, and I want to run a simple shell command to use a certain version of NVM:

Here is my code snippet:

```
print "\n*** Switching to correct nvm environment for dashboard builds\n";
system("nvm use 8.12.0") == 0 or die $?;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Can't exec "nvm": No such file or directory
```

Can someone help?

**Update (June 30, 2021):**
I also tried adding the command:

```
my $nvm_version = "8.12.0";
system ("bash", "-lic", "nvm use $nvm_version");
```

But nothing happens:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `nwm`, but I think I get the gist of what it does. And if so, the attempt is fundamentally flawed. Even if you fixed this to run the proper shell so that `nvm` could run, I believe all the tool does is change the shell's environment variables, a shell you immediately exit. This means it would have no effect even if if it ran successfully.

Again, it this tool does what I think it does, such tool are meant to be used in *interactive shells*. In other instances, you simply use the path the to correct executable instead of relying on the PATH.

With that in mind, you can use the following to run the command in `bash`:

```perl
# Non-interactive shell.
system("bash", "-c", "nvm use 8.12.0")
```

or

```perl
# Interactive shell.
# This is improper and fragile as interactive shells
# often create aliases that override basic commands.
system("bash", "-ic", "nvm use 8.12.0")
```

Just to reiterate, at least one of these will allow the command to run (if it normally works from bash), but I believe it's unlikely this will produce the results you expect.

Comment: It's basically "perlbrew for node.js".

Comment: I tried this, but still get the error: bash: nvm: command not found

Comment: Updated my post above.

Comment: @tobyink , Re "*It's basically "perlbrew for node.js"*", yeah, and I assumed it works in a similar fashion, and I assumed the solution is the same: "you simply use the path the to correct executable instead of relying on the PATH."

Comment: Re "*Updated my post above*" & *But nothing happens*",  Just like my answer said would happen. My answer explains why: "all the tool does is change the shell's environment variables, a shell you immediately exit"

Answer (score 1):

The `nvm` command is [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) which is different from a shell command. Also the `nvm` command is not an exported function so it will not be seen by sub shells. For example, in Bash shell:

```
$ nvm ls
->      v15.0.1
$ my-test-script.sh
./my-test-script.sh: line 3: nvm: command not found
```

where `my-test-script.sh` is:

```
#! /bin/bash

nvm use 16.4
```

The error `nvm: command not found` is because `nvm` is not exported. I can source the script in the current shell context to make it work:

```
$ source my-test-script.sh
Now using node v16.4.0 (npm v7.18.1)
$ node --version
v16.4.0
```

So a Perl script cannot change the `node` version of the current shell, but it can calculate the version and pass it back to shell, which can set the version. For example:

```
$ nvm use $(perl -E'$v=15.0; print $v')
Now using node v15.0.1 (npm v7.0.3)
```

Comment: Thanks, Håkon Hægland, but you still haven't answered my question.  Are you saying that I cannot switch nvm environments with a perl script.  It needs to be done only on the command line?  What about ikegami's comment about the path to the actual executable?